# How to Print a float that u read from the screen

Tags: java

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
float r = 0, r2 = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

try {
    System.out.print("First number ");
    x = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("second number ");
    y = in.nextInt();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
    System.exit(0);
}

r = (x * x) / y;
r2 = (y * y) / x;
System.out.printf("Results are " + r + " and" + r2);
```

Ok i need to read 2 integers from keyboard then make a division a get a float, How do i get a float? I need x and y to be integers

If x = 2 and y = 3 I'll get `1.0` and `4.0` but I need to show 1.333 and 4.5

Also im getting "the assigned value is never used" for all the variables why?

Comment: [Here's the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat%28%29) look at it

Answer (score 0):

When you divide two integers you get [integer division](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2), cast the first to a float -

```
r = ((float)(x*x))/y;
r2 = ((float)(y*y))/x;
```

As linked, the JLS says (**bold** and *italics* added) -

> ... the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) **is** an *integer* value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.

Answer (score 0):

have you cast the result into a float using (float) command?
e.g. System.out.printf("Results are " + (float)r + " and" + (float) r2);

Answer (score 0):

You can cast all results to float(r, r2), it's more readable and organized, but the answers before are absolutely correct :D

Your code with a little fix:

```
   int x = 0, y = 0;
   float r = 0, r2 = 0;
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   try {
      System.out.print("First number ");
      x = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("second number ");
      y = in.nextInt();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Not a number");
      System.exit(0);
   }

   r = ((float)(x * x) / y);
   r2 = ((float)(y * y) / x);
   System.out.printf("Results are " + r + " and" + r2);
```